# Quiero extraer el id autoincrementable al momento de insertar el registro

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Necesito guardar los id's en la variable $last[], pero me guarda vacio o cero.
El sp_ins_ott_registro() es un sp que inserta en una tabla de 5 atributos, los que se ven ahi y el AI.

De esta manera me devuelve cero.

```
            for ($i=0; $i <$contadorArray1; $i++) { 
                $sqlRegistroMuestra="call sp_ins_ott_registro_muestra($ottNumero,'$arrayConPosiciones[$i]',".$arrayConValores[$i].",'".$m1."');";
                $mysqli_obra->query($sqlRegistroMuestra);
                $last[]= $mysqli_obra->insert_id;
                echo "$sqlRegistroMuestra";
            }
```

De la siguiente me devuelve vacio

```
            for ($i=0; $i <$contadorArray1; $i++) { 
                $sqlRegistroMuestra="call sp_ins_ott_registro_muestra($ottNumero,'$arrayConPosiciones[$i]',".$arrayConValores[$i].",'".$m1."');";
                $mysqli_obra->query($sqlRegistroMuestra);
                $last[]= $mysqli_obra->query("select LAST_INSERT_ID()");
                echo "$sqlRegistroMuestra";
            }
```

De esta también devuelve vació

```
for ($i=0; $i <$contadorArray1; $i++) { 
            $sqlRegistroMuestra="call sp_ins_ott_registro_muestra($ottNumero,'$arrayConPosiciones[$i]',".$arrayConValores[$i].",'".$m1."');";
            $mysqli_obra->query($sqlRegistroMuestra);
            $last[]= mysql_insert_id();
            echo "$sqlRegistroMuestra";
        }
```

Comment: Sin saber que hace `sp_ins_ott_registro_muestra`es imposible ayudarte.

Comment: Ese es el sp `CREATE DEFINER=`usr_obras_civiles`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_ins_ott_registro_muestra`(
 in id_ott int,
    id_tipo_muestra int,
    valor decimal,
    descripcion varchar(45)
)
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO `lacem_obras_civiles`.`msa_registro_muestra` (`id_ott`, `id_tipo_muestra`, `valor`, `descripcion`) VALUES (id_ott, id_tipo_muestra, valor,'descripcion');
END`

Answer (score 0):

Para devolver la última id que has insertado necesitas añadir en tu procedimiento almacenado `sp_ins_ott_registro_muestra` la sguiente línea:

```
//Imaginando que haces un insert de un nombre de usuario
INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName) VALUES ('Jean');

//Una vez insertado recuperamos la id
SELECT ID AS LastID FROM Persons WHERE ID = @@Identity;
```

Tendrás que adecuar el código ya que no se la consulta que realizas, pero espero que la idea te haya quedado clara.